# Display value of sorting after each iteration

Tags: c++

```
void insertionSort(vector<Comparable> & a) {
    for(int p = 1; p < a.size(); ++p) {
        Comparable tmp = a[p];
        int j;
        for(j = p; j > 0 && tmp < a[j - 1]; --j)
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

How can I show the step by step sorting of this function? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Trace through it with your debugger.  Makes it easy:)

Comment: do you want to copy the results of the individual steps or simply output them?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#/media/File:Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif).

Comment: I want to output them. Sorry for the wrong indention. Its my first time here

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a cout statement with a loop like this:

```
for(int k=0; k<a.size(); k++)
    cout<<a[k]<<"\n";
```

This should be added to your code like this:

```
void insertionSort(vector<Comparable> & a) {
    for(int p = 1; p < a.size(); ++p) {
        Comparable tmp = a[p];
        int j;
        for(j = p; j > 0 && tmp < a[j - 1]; --j)
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        a[j] = tmp;
        for(int k=0; k<a.size(); k++)
            cout<<a[k]<<"\n";
    }
}
```